# Windows 10 Pro license, is a license for Windows 7 and 8 too

Tags: windows-10

It is written in the license agreement of Windows 10 Professional that the user can use a Windows 7 or Windows 8 too. Where can a user with a licensed Windows 10 Pro can download these Windows and how can they get a product key to activate them?

Does the user have to install these Windows on the same computer alongside windows 10 or can they install them on other computers?

---

> Downgrade Rights. If you acquired a device from a manufacturer or
>   installer with a Professional version of Windows preinstalled on it,
>   you may use either a Windows 8.1 Pro or Windows 7 Professional
>   version, but only for so long as Microsoft provides support for that
>   earlier version as set forth in (aka.ms/windowslifecycle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *only* do this on a machine that you've bought from an OEM with windows 10, and replace the *current* OS with an older one. This is for companies that have standardized on an older version, as opposed to 'additional' licences you can run alongside the windows 10 system in the same hardware, or different hardware.

Its an *either* windows 10 *or* other version licence.

Comment: where can I download and how can I activate?

Comment: Contact the OEM/installer for details - they'd likely supply you with the key and a download link for the media.